# Получение подстроки после определенного набора символов (например !sen)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как получить часть строки после `!sen`? После `!sen` может быть любое значение из букв\цифр и примеры:

1. `!senword`
2. `!sen123`
3. `!senword123`

Делаю так:

```
$sen = explode("!sen", $s);
```

но интересует каким способом быстрее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос, то можно воспользоваться функцией [substr()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php)

```
<?php
/**
 * В данной функции параметр $fromChar не обязательный,
 * по умолчанию он указывает на позицию символа после которого
 * нужно будет вырезать строку, он пригодится в том случае
 * когда Вы решите отбросить не !sen а допустим !se или !senw
 */
function foo($string, $fromChar=4)
{
    return substr($string, $fromChar);
}
// ну и проверка
echo foo('!senword'); // выведет word
echo foo('!sen123');  // выведет 123

$testString = foo('!senword123', 3);
echo $testString; // выведет nword123
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Лучше так:

```
print ("<br>".str_replace("!sen", "", "!senword"));
print ("<br>".str_replace("!sen", "", "!sen123"));
print ("<br>".str_replace("!sen", "", "!senword123"));
```

Результат:

```
word
123
word123
```